# Report viewer width problem in Mozila

Tags: asp.net, html, css, reporting-services, mozilla

Report viewer width/height is not display properly in `Mozila Firefox`, but perfectly displayed in `IE`. Dispaly size in Mozila is `450 width and 175 height` and perfectly in `IE` shown in full page. I have set width in px instead of %age but getting same.
Does anyone have solution of this issue?
here is my `.aspx page source`

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="divException" runat="server" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 100px"
    visible="false">
    <asp:Label ID="lblException" runat="server" Text="Sorry, no data found!!!" Font-Size="Large"
        ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptvReport" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="95%">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have using SQL Reporting Services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very Tricky solution......

Adding this style, resolve the problem, but some features missing as Microsoft pointed
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx

```
 <style type="text/css">
    html, body, form
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    table#rptvReport
    {
        display: table !important;
        background-color:White;
        min-height:500px;
    }
</style>
```

where this is **rptvReport** the ID of the ReportViewer, here should be set the ID of your ReportView control.
Actually what was the problem here is, When report is rendered a table has style property like

```
style="display:inline-block"
```

that is creating problem, what I have did here is changing this into

```
 display: table !important;
```

and that resolve the problem

Comment: Thanks. I added this code to the SSRS Server page (ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx).  I only had to change   table#rptvReport to table#ReportViewerControl.

Answer (score 1):

this is the known issue and some features does not supported by MS SQL Reporting Services in Mozila, Safari, ....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1419932.aspx?View=Flat

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/f842430b-8586-46eb-a144-c498191681e9/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1174296.aspx?View=Flat

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=105014

Answer (score 0):

Are you triggering quirks mode in IE, by chance? Anyway it is hard to tell what happens, unless you specify the styles applied to all the higher level elements (body?)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply
I have only add the following style in head tag and nothing else define in the page. 
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

That helped me for the width problem...

> Browse to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx
>
> Add info to the  tag style property.

```
<RS:ReportViewerHost style="display:table; margin: 0px; overflow: auto" ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" .....
```

from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/d5157c21-f271-4f17-bac4-3e27dbc9e0cf).

Print and search won't work. We create the pdf-document and use that for printing and searching...

Comment: I am unable to find next to this directory
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
here I found MSSQL.1 and MSSQL.2 but not found MSSQL.3 and so on.....